# how to write sql statement in c# to join data

Tags: c#, mysql, select, join

Im trying to join data from different tables and displaying them in datagrid, but im getting an error.

I'm trying to get this info from those tables. Btw, the users needs to type in his id.

**RESERVATIONS**

**UPDATE**

" + this.UserID + " is an actual ID of user (int)

bookingID : 1 (int)

bookID : 3 (int)

userID : 1 (int)

**USERS**

Name : Jack (string)

LastName : Jones (string)

**BOOKS**

NameOfTheBook : Lord of the Rings (string)

**END RESULT**

1, 3, 1 Jack Jones, Lord of the Rings (in a data grid table)

```
string Query = 
    "SELECT bookingID, bookID, userID, Name, LastName, NameOfTheBook " + 
    "FROM Reservations, Users, Books "+
    "WHERE userID = " + thisUserID.Text + 
    " AND Users.ID = " + thisUserID.Text + 
    " AND Books.ID = " + thisUserID.Text + "";
```

**ERROR**
The value of at least one of the required parameters has not been determined

How do I fix it?

Comment: You need to look into [Joins](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

Comment: It appears that you may be missing some fields in your tables.  Is there a USERS.userID and a BOOKS.bookID?  If so, I'd modify the query so that you join these three tables together on these values.

Comment: @STLDeveloper no they are not. they only exist under Reservations, but i do not know how to do it differently. Any tips?

Comment: Have you looked at the existing values of bookID and UserID in the Reservations table?  Is it possible that bookID is actually Books.NameOfTheBook and userID is Users.Name?  Perhaps there's another table in the database that you have yet to discover.

Comment: Do what @KevinKunderman said. Read that link on joins and it'll give you a better idea on how to structure your tables to facilitate joining tables together.

Comment: @STLDeveloper i just updated the post. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Step through it and take a look at what Query evaluates to. I suspect it might be you're not linking on the correct fields.

Should it read like more this? :

```
string Query = 
"SELECT bookingID, bookID, userID, Name, LastName, NameOfTheBook " + 
"FROM Reservations, Users, Books "+
"WHERE userID = " + thisUserID.Text + 
" AND Users.ID = Reservations.userID"
" AND Books.ID = Reservations.bookID";
```

If userID is a text field then you'd have to put triple quotes in instead of single to get the userID wrapped correctly.

Comment: If the value of thisUserID.Text is always a number, the quotations won't matter. Also, always a catch, I think you'll need to use single quotes in side the SQL query (your solution uses double quotes - right track though!) I think it's an issue other than quotations, as another user posted there should really be some joins used in this query. Hard to test without sample data.

Comment: Just realised that exact same thing and edited accordingly. Without knowing what data type userID there's not a lot to go on.

Comment: @fkr, you need IDs on your two other tables to be able to link to them. Please do check out the article on Joins linked in the question comments as it's not only fundamental to what you are trying to achieve but to using relational tables in general.